# Not able to call API with Authorization Token in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to call an API to get current user details and need to attach token with the `Authorization` header. However it is failing to call API with 500 error response.

It is working absolutely fine from Postman and curl command and I am getting user details.

Code for it as below:

```
httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders ({         
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});

getCurrentUser(url){     
  var token = localStorage.getItem('token');     
  this.httpHeaders = this.httpHeaders.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`);
  return this.http.get<any>(url, { headers: this.httpHeaders });
}
```

I tried different ways to concatenate token with Bearer prefix however getting Authorization in console as Bearer "token-string" (not sure if this is the reason my API is failing).

Comment: Can you check if it is cors issue?

Comment: Please do a `console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))` and check if it actually contains the token. You could also check in the browser DevTools window. It's under **Storage** section in Firefox and **Application** section in Chrome.

Comment: Aside from the redundant `localStorage.getItem('token')`, everything looks fine. A `500` error code indicates an internal server error. You should check with your server and check for any error logs that can give your more information about whats going wrong.  A missing token in your localStorage could also be a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. CORS is fine. Issue has been resolved once I tried                                                                'Authorization': `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))}` .

Answer (score 1):

```js
  public getCurrentUser(url: string): Observable<unknown> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    // Launch DevTools to step through the code in the debugger;
    debugger;
    // check if token is valid string as well
    if (token == null) {
      throw new Error('Authorization token not found');
    }
    // Use local object
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    });
    return this.http.get<unknown>(url, { headers: httpHeaders });
  }
```

If you still receive `HTTP 500 internal server` error from server:

- Open DevTools and review the error messages in `Console` or `Network` tab if any.
- Review the server logs if you have access to them.